# How can I format the date and time in accordance with ISO 8601 / RFC 3339 using systemd?

Tags: systemd, date, locale, i18n

How can I configure the **environment** of a systemd based Linux system to display the date system-wide in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`?

This date format adheres to the specifications defined [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339).

Comment: Try this `export LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8` Some applications unfortunately don't respect it, including journalctl.

Comment: With journalctl you can use `-o short-iso`.

Comment: Are you specifically referring to the timestamps in `systemd` ouput via `journalctl`, or more generally including tools such as `date` (without arguments)?

Comment: @roaima I mean the environment configuration with `localectl` on systemd.